# Usando IF com Eval asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
<%# Eval("filiacao").ToString() == "nada consta" ? "nada consta" : "+infos" %>
```

Quero que "+infos" seja um link.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: **`<a href="link">+infos</a>`** não serve?

Comment: não dá pra usar assim.

Comment: E por que não dá?

Comment: porque espera uma resposta da expressão e isso não é uma resposta acredito. Só sei que não dá pra usar, pois tentei de diversas formas utilizar essa sugestão.

Comment: Taí uma questão simples mas difícil. Talvez eu tenha que mudar a forma.

Comment: `<%# Eval("filiacao").ToString() == "nada consta" ? "nada consta" : "<a href='link'>+infos</a>" %>` assim não funciona?

Comment: pior q funcionou assim. waleu gente pelas dicas. O apóstrofe fez toda a diferença.